# I'm trying to install React, but I obtain the error below, how can I fix them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to install with:
npx create-react-app my-app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxoOe.png)

> PS D:\Programming\Js\React> npx create-react-app my-app

> npm ERR! code ENOENT

> npm ERR! syscall lstat

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\NGUYEN THI PHUC\AppData\Roaming\npm

> npm ERR! errno -4058

> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\NGUYEN
> THI PHUC\AppData\Roaming\npm'

> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

> npm ERR! enoent

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

> npm ERR!     C:\Users\NGUYEN THI PHUC\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023 07-08T04_35_31_903Z-debug-0.log

I use npm 9.5.1, nodejs 18.16.1

I tried redownload my nodejs but it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you try to make a folder there and see what happens?

Comment: It seems that you have installed `nodejs` for a different user and trying to create react app using another user. Your can use admin mode for both the operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess npm 9.5.1 and Node.js 18.16.1, do not align with the typical versioning scheme for npm and Node.js. You can use the latest stable version of the both .

clean the npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`.
Make sure You have proper access to these commands if you are using windows.

Uninstall and reinstall create-react-app:

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Then, reinstall create-react-app globally using the following command:
`npm install -g create-react-app`

After  these steps, try running the create-react-app command again:

`npx create-react-app my-app`

This should work now .

Answer (score 0):

the npm command is unable to find a file or directory, specifically C:\Users\NGUYEN THI PHUC\AppData\Roaming\npm. This issue can be caused by various reasons such as missing or corrupted files

npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app

Check if the npm directory exists in your user directory (C:\Users\NGUYEN THI PHUC\AppData\Roaming).

Verify that the npm directory is added to your system's PATH environment variable. To check this

echo %PATH%

Look for the path that includes npm (e.g., C:\Users\NGUYEN THI PHUC\AppData\Roaming\npm). If its missing you need to add it to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

[subfolder npm needs to be manually created!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDYLQ.png)

I got that error today on a fresh install of React/Next when trying to create my first React Project ().
As suggested by "yxre" I manually created the missing "npm" subfolder and I have been able to create a project ("npx create-expo-app").

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!